# Cannot find symbol method get() using picasso library

Tags: android, picasso

After an Android Studio's Invalidate Cache and rebuild the project, Picasso is getting an error, and cannot find the get() method.

The full error message is just "*error: cannot find symbol method get()*".

My build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

and the code that i'm using:

```
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

// rest of the code

Picasso.get()
       .load(user.getImage())
       .error(R.drawable.img_standard)
       .into(bannerImageView);

// ...
```

I saw a similar issue with the old method, Picasso.with(), but the get() method I cannot find a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually a good idea after a cache invalidation to do a gradle sync and wait for Android Studio to finish the reindexing. After these, do a build, this should fix the problem in most cases.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old but this answer may help of someone,
I had the same issue to resolve it instead of using this using .get()

```
Picasso.get().load(imageURL).into(imageView);
```

I used it using .with()

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imageURL).into(imageView);
```

Picasso version used

```
com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
```

Answer (score -2):

Edit your dependencies to import the new provider
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso-provider:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
Replacing `Picasso.get()` with `PicassoProvider.get()`
Be aware that the API may change again at any time